# Change password in Android

Tags: php

I am having problem when trying to change the password in my application. It keep showing current password is invalid. It might be problem from my PHP coding. But I can't find the problem. This is my code for PHP.

```
<?php

require ("config1.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $lecID = $_GET['lecID'];
    $query = "UPDATE lecturer SET lecPass= :lec_Pass WHERE lecID = '$lecID' ";
    $query_params = array(':lec_Pass'=> $_POST['lecPass']);

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please try again";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $validate_info = false;
    // Fetching rows from query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($row) {
        if ($_POST['lecPass'] === $row['lecPass']) {
            $changePass_ok = true;
        }
    }
    if ($changePass_ok) {
        // UserLogin
        $response['success'] = 1;
        $response['message'] = "Password changed successfully";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
    else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Failure";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
}

?>
```

Appreciate if someone can guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you really storing passwords in plain text? Are you saying your're getting a message of "Failure" returned?

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST)){

$lecID=$_GET['lecID'];` You check that the $_POST array is not empty, but then try to get the value from the $_GET array. This makes no sense. If the user is sending a POST request, then there will never be any data in $_GET. Try `$lecID=$_POST['lecID'];`

Comment: And yeah, as pointed out, storing your passwords in plain text is very bad for security.

Comment: @ADyson Huh? Sure there can. OP could send a POST and still have GET params in the URL.

Comment: @JonStirling yeah I guess they could...doh. Brain not switched on.

Comment: Actually this is probably it: `$row = $stmt->fetch();

        if ($row){
            if($_POST['lecPass'] === $row['lecPass']){
                $changePass_ok=true; }
` Doing a fetch on an UPDATE statement is never going to return any rows.

Comment: @ADyson Yep, that would do it. Good catch.

Comment: @JonStirling Plain text **over HTTP**, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh dear.

Comment: What do Java and Android have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(); 
if ($row){ 
  if($_POST['lecPass'] === $row['lecPass']){ 
    $changePass_ok=true; 
  }
}
```

This isn't going to work. Doing a `fetch()` on an UPDATE statement is never going to return anything, because UPDATE statements don't return rows. There is nothing to compare.

You have two options:

1) Simply check that the UPDATE statement succeeded. This should really be sufficient evidence that the password was successfully updated, without having to select the row out again.

2) The lengthier way, more similar to what you're trying now is that, following the UPDATE, you run a separate SELECT statement to fetch the same row again from the database and compare the value returned against the $_POST value.

N.B. As others have pointed out in the comments, storing your passwords in plain text and transmitting them over unencrypted HTTP is incredibly insecure and asking for trouble. You should switch to HTTPS and also store the passwords in your database using a one-way hash, so that anyone with access to the DB cannot immediately steal the passwords. Then when the user logs in, you hash the password value they supply using the same algorithm, and compare *that* with the value in the DB in order to validate the login.

Comment: "my password are store in database not in plain text. " They're stored in plain text _within_ the database. So if you look in the database your can read the passwords exactly as typed by the user, without unencrypyting them. I'm not talking about text files. This design is insecure compared to using hashing techniques, which are impossible/extremely difficult to reverse-engineer.

Comment: Re option 2, an UPDATE statement does not return any results. If you want to look at the new contents of your updated row, you need to run a SELECT command and return that row. I don't know how else to explain that. But personally I think option 1 is better because it's less code and also the server does less work (one less query is required)